# in Classic ASP, How to get if a dynamic array has elements inside?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript, dynamic-arrays

If I declare a dynamic sized array like this

```
Dim myArray()
```

Then how I can get in the code if this array is empty or it contains elements?

I tried with `IsArray(myArray)` function that give me always True,

otherwise if I try with `UBound(myArray)` function, I get an error.

Any ideas? thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: UBound(myArray) also fails when in an if conditional? 
As in: if UBound(myArray) <> 0 then...

Comment: I always get the same error with UBound() function: "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' Subscript out of range: 'UBound'", this is because the array is not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

After declaring the array, you have to initialize it:

```
Dim myArray()
ReDim myArray(-1)
```

Then such code will always work:

```
If UBound(myArray)<0 Then
    'array is empty....
Else  
    'array not empty....
End If
```

Edit: as you can't initialize the array, here is longer way to check if it's empty or not:

```
Dim x, myCount
myCount = 0
If IsArray(myArray) Then
    For Each x In myArray
        myCount = myCount + 1
    Next
End If
If myCount=0 Then
    'array is empty....
Else  
    'array not empty....
End If
```

Comment: I dont want initialize the array. In same part of the code, if I dont know if the array is already initialized, I need to check this before.

Comment: i found a smarter solution. tnx again

Answer (score 2):

First some notes.

1. Using `Dim A()` is not so practical in VBScript, better use `ReDim
   A(n)`.
2. For example `ReDim A(-1)` is also empty array (no elements) but **initialized**.

And as the best way coders to talk is by examples...

```
Dim a(), b(0), c
c = Array(a, b)
ReDim d(-1)

WScript.Echo "Testing HasBound:"
WScript.Echo "a = " & HasBound(a) & ",", _
             "b = " & HasBound(b) & ",", _
             "c = " & HasBound(c) & ",", _
             "d = " & HasBound(d)
WScript.Echo "Testing HasItems:"
WScript.Echo "a = " & HasItems(a) & ",", _
             "b = " & HasItems(b) & ",", _
             "c = " & HasItems(c) & ",", _
             "d = " & HasItems(d)

'> Testing HasBound:
'> a = False, b = True, c = True, d = True
'> Testing HasItems:
'> a = False, b = True, c = True, d = False

Function HasBound(anyArray)
    On Error Resume Next
    HasBound = UBound(anyArray)
    HasBound = (0 = Err)
    On Error Goto 0
End Function

Function HasItems(anyArray)
    For Each HasItems In anyArray
        HasItems = 1
        Exit For
    Next
    HasItems = (HasItems > 0)
End Function
```

As you see, 2 functions with different purpose. The difference is visible on array `d` which "has-boundary" but "has-not-items".

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I wrote a specific function to check if an array is null or not; the function doesn't check if it has elements inside but only if the array is declared as dynamic without dimensions and no elements.

```
Dim dynamic_array()                         'array without a dimension
Dim empty_array(0)                          'array with a dimension but without an element inside
Dim full_array(0) : full_array(0) = "max"   'array with a dimension and with an element inside


Function IsNullArray(input_array)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim is_null : is_null = UBound(input_array)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        is_null = False
    Else
        is_null = True
    End If
    IsNullArray = is_null
End Function


If IsNullArray(dynamic_array) Then

    Response.Write("<p>dynamic array not 'ReDimed'</p>")

End If

If Not IsNullArray(empty_array) Then

    Response.Write("<p>" & UBound(empty_array) & "</p>") 'return the last index  of the array

End If

If Not IsNullArray(full_array) Then

    Response.Write("<p>" & full_array(UBound(full_array)) & "</p>") 'return the value of the last element of the array

End If
```

Comment: I wrote the following 3-4 years ago: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2008-02/msg00223.html worth reading if you really want to get under-the-hood of this.

Comment: BTW your If-Else-Endif 5 lines could be reduced to `is_null = (Err.Number = 0)` and you could dispense with the is_null variable altogether eliminating 2 more statements.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can think of right now is:

```
On Error resume next
if UBound(myArray) < 0 then response.write "Empty array" end if
```

EDIT: Max's comment

Comment: If UBound(myArray) function return "0" then myArray is not empty but it contains one element.

Comment: Can I see your code? Those two lines are working fine for me with "myArray" just declared like this: Dim myArray().

Answer (score 0):

I've always checked for UBound = 0 and the first element is empty too:

```
If UBound(myArray) = 0 Then
    if myArray(0) = "" then ''Depending on the type of the array
       ''array is empty....
    End If
End If
```