# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]' Include/Security.inc, line 28

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

Im working in a migration project.

Where im trying to migrate classic asp application. Im not good at Classic ASP.

i had taken the code from the server and trying to run it in my machine. But getting the following error.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a0009'
>
> Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]'
>
> /Include/Security.inc, line 28

Please find the block of code where im getting the error.

```
Function StringConvUN
    dim tabConv
    dim rmLocation
    dim username
    username = Ucase(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
    if UCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")) = "SITEMINDER" then
        StringConvUN = username
    else
        tabConv = split(username, "'")
        rmLocation = join(tabConv, "''")
        tabConv = split(rmLocation , "\")
        StringConvUN = tabConv(1)
    end if
End Function
```

Im getting the error in line 28 which is

> StringConvUN = tabConv(1)

The same code is running fine in the IIS 6 server. But in my machine and in new IIS 7.5 server it giving the above error. please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check to see whether you're using the correct authentication method in IIS, as well as what Amessihel has mentioned above. But the code looks a little messy here...

```vb
tabConv = split(username, "'")
rmLocation = join(tabConv, "''")
tabConv = split(rmLocation , "\")
StringConvUN = tabConv(1)
```

Why not just `Replace` your single quotes with doubles in the initial copy of the `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")`, like so:

```vb
username = Replace(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), "'", "''")
```

And you could simply use a combination of `Instr` and `Mid` to obtain the string you want...

```vb
tabconv = Mid(UCase(Replace(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), "'",   "''")), _
  Instr(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), "\") + 1)
```

But check IIS first.

Comment: Better answer indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `StringConvUN` is empty before getting the first element...

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315949/4375327). This is a home-made function checking if an array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for position 1 in the array, which in this case does not exist, try taking the last position in the array, i.e. everything after the '\'

```
StringConvUN = tabConv(uBound(tabConv))
```

Comment: Doesn't uBound return an error if the array is empty ?

Comment: @andydavey: Why? If the first position of the array doesn't exist, then the last certainly doesn't. Besides, the array is generated from breaking a string into parts based on the position of the '\' character. Check the original string then you don't need to mess with checking a possibly undefined array.

Comment: In the OPs example, uBoud will return -1 if the 'username' does not contain a '\' - the array will still be null though ... which leads onto Pauls comment ...

Comment: @Paul - you are right - if the correct authentication method is set on IIS then "Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))" will return something.  If something is returned then using array(uBound(array)) will return a value whether login name contains '\' or not.

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @AndyDavey: Even if IIS authentication is not set properly, the resultant value would be an empty string which can still be tested easily without chance of errors.